# How to get the Operating Profit Graph for the entire game?

Tags: openttd

The game shows it only for last few years:

[image]

Is it possible to get similar graph for the entire game duration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible.  The game only stores the company history for the past 24 quarters (6 years).  Source: looking through the game's source code.  In the file `company_type.h` is the line

```
static const uint MAX_HISTORY_QUARTERS            = 24; ///< The maximum number of quarters kept as performance's history
```